# Why is Powershell & AD returning newlines?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have this Powershell code:

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(Description=*MD))"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$colProplist = "name", "department", "description"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()

foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$objItem = $objResult.Properties
         $objItem.name + "|" + $objItem.department + "|" + $objItem.description
    }
```

For some reason it's returning new lines. How can I stop this?

The output looks like:

```
Bob Dole
|
SOME DEPT
|
Bob description
Rick James
|
ANOTHER DEPT
|
Rick description
```

Changing the last block to:

```
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$objItem = $objResult.Properties
         $colResults.Properties|%{($_.name,$_.department,$_.description) -join "|"}
    }
```

Doesn't give me anything, just a bunch of:

```
||
||
||
||
||
||
```

I also tried just:

```
$colResults.Properties|%{($_.name,$_.department,$_.description) -join "|"}
```

And only got:

```
||
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware that `$objItem.attribute` is always a collection. I suspect that this is root cause of the problems you are seeing. Try this:

```sh
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$objItem = $objResult.Properties
         $objItem.name[0] + "|" + $objItem.department[0] + "|" + $objItem.description[0]
    }
```

The problem is that this can give your errors if any of these attributes is empty. To avoid it (and get the same experience) you can use unary `-join` (with `-f` to make it easier to read):

```sh
foreach ($objResult in $colResults)
    {$objItem = $objResult.Properties
         '{0}|{1}|{2}' -f @(
            (-join $objItem.name)
            (-join $objItem.department) 
            (-join $objItem.description)
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just join them instead:

```
($objItem.Name,$objItem.Department,$objItem.Description) -join "|"
```

That should give you your desired output.

Alternatively you could use string formatting like this:

```
"{0}|{1}|{2}" -f $objItem.Name, $objItem.Department, $objItem.Description
```

**Edit:** Ok, this runs on my machine and returns the results you wanted:

```
$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(Description=*MD))"

$objDomain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry

$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$objSearcher.SearchRoot = $objDomain
$objSearcher.PageSize = 1000
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter
$objSearcher.SearchScope = "Subtree"

$colProplist = "name", "department", "description"
foreach ($i in $colPropList){$objSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add($i)}

$colResults = $objSearcher.FindAll()
$colResults.Properties|%{($($_['name']),$($_['department']),$($_['description'])) -join "|"}
```

Comment: Neither of those worked. The first gave me `@{Name=; Department=; Description=}` on every line. The 2nd gave me a bunch of `||`

Comment: Updated answer, with some explanation of my process and examples of how I got what I did.

Comment: No luck, same issue. See OP for updated code I'm trying.

Comment: Right, because you don't have an object named $Array. I updated my answer again to help you adapt it to your needs.

Comment: Oh whoops. Updated code, same issue. See OP. I'm under the impression here the `... $objResult.Properties <your code>` makes this join incompatible? Just a guess.

Comment: Hmm, `Replace that entire block:` confuses me. I'm suppose to wipe out those 4 lines? I just tried that too, and only got 1 line returned with the blank `||`

Comment: Wow, ok, I wasn't aware that $colResults.Properties was a hashtable. I'm sorry, I'm used to using the ActiveDirectory module which is SO much simpler than all this. I updated my answer with code that I tested using your entire script (I changed $strFilter to just return a few accounts, and replaced the last 4 lines as noted in my answer). This will return what you want.

Comment: I tried that too in place of the 4 lines, and got an error `Cannot index into a null array.`

Comment: Try copying and pasting the script at in the answer into PowerShell and see if it works. I have it in there in it's entirety now, so you can just copy/paste the whole thing.

Comment: Copy-pasted in, same error but 3 times. Char 32, char 46 and char 66.

Comment: Is there anything *in* $colResults.Properties?

Comment: `$colResults` is a bunch of `System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult`. Maybe there's no Properties because we have to dig into those and loop through them. But yes `$colResults` has results, and so does my original code which dug into objResult